# Concatenate string elements in a list on the basis of delimiters

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, delimiter

I am trying to combine all the elements in a list on the basis of some delimiters; I am facing difficulty when the delimiter pair is more than 1.

Say this is the list :

```
['{','k0c','k1b','k2b','k3b','}','{','\\g0','\\g1','\\g2','\\g3','}']
```

12 items in this list

Whenever it finds '{' and '}' I want all of the elements within those indexes to be concatenated into one so that it is:

```
['{ k0c, k1b, k2b, k3b }' , '{\\g0 , \\g1, \\g2, \\g3 }' ]
```

2 items in this list are what I want with all the elements inside the delimiters turned into one element of the list.

Comment: Can you have nested pairs?

Comment: Could you please elaborate by nested? Are you talking about list of list?

Comment: Meaning will an opening brace always be followed by a closing brace before another opening brace? or can you have something like `["{", "a", "{", "b", "}", "c", "}"]`?

Comment: Oh no.. I won't have any nested brace. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this oughta do the trick:

```py
input_data = [
    "{",
    "k0c",
    "k1b",
    "k2b",
    "k3b",
    "}",
    "{",
    "\\g0",
    "\\g1",
    "\\g2",
    "\\g3",
    "}",
]
lists = []
current_list = None

for atom in input_data:
    if atom == "{":
        assert current_list is None, "nested lists not supported"
        current_list = []
        lists.append(current_list)
    elif atom == "}":
        current_list.append(atom)
        current_list = None
        continue
    assert current_list is not None, (
        "attempting to add item when no list active: %s" % atom
    )
    current_list.append(atom)

for lst in lists:
    print(" ".join(lst))
```

The output is

```
{ k0c k1b k2b k3b }
{ \g0 \g1 \g2 \g3 }
```

but you can do whatever you like with the lists of strings.

Comment: The output should be: 

{ k0c, k1b, k2b, k3b }
{ \g0, \g1, \g2, \g3 }

Comment: As said, you can do anything you like with the lists, for instance `', '.join(lst)` if you need commas.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data does not have any degenerate cases, we will always expect a `'}','{'` to separate your groups.

Therefore a simple way to get your desired output would be to join the strings together, split on `}` and then format the resulting list elements.

```
l = ['{','k0c','k1b','k2b','k3b','}','{','\\g0','\\g1','\\g2','\\g3','}']
out = [x.replace("{,", "{").strip(", ") + " }" for x in ", ".join(l).split("}") if x]
print(out)
['{ k0c, k1b, k2b, k3b }', '{ \\g0, \\g1, \\g2, \\g3 }']
```

Comment: Can I ask for a little elaboration on what the 'for x in' and 'if x' parts are doing in this line? @pault

Comment: @zaki that is called a list comprehension. [What does “list comprehension” mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Comment: if there are multiple {  } {  } {  } {  } will this code do it for all of them ?
I still can't figure out why the if is there.

Comment: @zaki the `if` is there to handle the final `}`. The best way to understand is to try it with and without. Try it piece by piece- first the `join`, then the `split`, etc...